# webDAV-Client on several platforms

Tags: html, client, webdav

some rather general question from me:

My client is looking forward to get a `webDAV`-client from me. He wants it to be compatible with `android`, `ios`, `winPhone`, `firefox-OS` (and `ubuntu-OS`, when its done). I am used to code native apps and now i'm a bit confused how to solve this best.

Will this be possible using `html-5` + `jquery/JS` ?? i got no expierience in this direction so far. Thanks for any advice :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well you certainly can call some WebDAV methods with javascript. Wether or not everything is implementable highly depends on other the functionality your client expects.